# How to install Hydra 8 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

How can I install [Hydra](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) on my Ubuntu 14.04?
Please be detailed as I'm still a newbie with Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hydra 7.5**

This package is in [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/hydra)

You can install `hydra` by:

```
sudo apt-get install hydra hydra-gtk
```

**Hydra 8.0**

This can be installed with the Launchpad reository [**ppa:pi-rho/security**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/security/+index?field.series_filter=trusty)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pi-rho/security

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install hydra
```